# Background image covers the game

Tags: java, swing, oop, jframe

I just started learning Java and I am trying to develop a simple game (pretty much like Space Invaders). I am trying to set up a background image to my game instead of just setting a color for the background.

Problem: The background image overrides/overlaps my game. I can't see my game anymore. How do I fix this?

Relevant Codes:

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements Runnable 
{

    private Player player;
    private Player2 player2;
    private EnemyWave enemyWave;
    private List<Guard> guards;

    private boolean inGame;
    private Integer lives;
    private Integer lives2;
    private String message;

    Board() 
    {

        JLabel backgroundImage;
        
        inGame=true;
        lives=3;
        lives2=3;

        player=new Player(START_X, START_Y);
        player2  =new Player2(START_X-180, START_Y);
        enemyWave = new EnemyWave();

        guards = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<6 ; i++) {
            guards.add(new Guard(GUARD_POSX + i * 125, GUARD_POSY));
        }


        addKeyListener(new KAdapter());
        setFocusable(true);
        //setBackground(new Color(168, 219, 127, 116)); // Background color
        
        // BACKGROUND IMAGE
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("background.jpg");
        backgroundImage = new JLabel("",img,JLabel.CENTER);
        backgroundImage.setBounds(0,0,1200,700);
        add(backgroundImage);
    
    setVisible(true);        
    }


    @Override
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();

        Thread animator = new Thread(this);
        animator.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;

        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while(inGame) {
            repaint();
            animationCycle();       //mechanics of a game

            timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
            sleep = DELAY - timeDiff;

            if(sleep<0) {
                sleep = 2;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleep);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            beforeTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        gameOver();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 18);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(font);

        g.drawString("Player 1 Lives: " + lives.toString(), BOARD_WIDTH - 185, 25);
        g.drawString("Enemies Left: " + enemyWave.getNumberOfEnemies().toString(), 28, 25);

        g.drawString("Player 2 Lives: " + lives2.toString(), BOARD_WIDTH - 185, 55);


        g.setColor(Color.GREEN); // border color where the plane lies
        g.drawLine(0, GROUND, BOARD_WIDTH, GROUND);

        player.draw(g, this);
        if (player.getM().isVisible())
            player.getM().draw(g, this);

        //create
        player2.draw(g, this);
        if (player2.getM().isVisible())
            player2.getM().draw(g, this);

        enemyWave.draw(g, this);

        for (Guard guard : guards) {
            guard.draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Before setting background image: [image: Before]

After setting background image (completely covered my game): [image: After]

Comment: You should add the swing tag.

Comment: Are you sure you're painting your background first, and then everything else ? I can't find where you `draw()` the background image in your code.

Comment: @Lutzi sorry I don't quite understand... do you meant something like this ---> g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null); ?

Comment: @NomadMaker sorry what do you mean by that?

Comment: @John I do. I see where you draw your strings, players, enemies and guards, but not the background image.

Comment: If you're using the Swing user interface, you should add the swing tag to your tags at the bottom (java, oop, etc). You should probably remove the game-engine and probably the game-development tags because you're not modifying a game-engine, and this is a basic rendering question.

Answer (score 1):

Swing has a parent/child relationship.

So a component will:

1. first paint itself based on the painting logic found in the paintComponent(...) method.
2. then paint any child components added to the panel.

In the constructor of your class you have:

```
add(backgroundImage);
```

which add the component to the panel, meaning it will paint on top of your custom painting.

Don't use a JLabel for your background.

Just paint the Image as the first step in your paintComponent(...) method.

Answer (score 0):

Added this in my Board class:

```
Image bg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("bg.jpg");
```

Added this in my paintComponent method:

```
g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
```

And it worked!